# Hibernate - understanding join queries generated using hql

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, hql

*Hibernate versions used:*

```
  <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>3.5.5-Final</version>

  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>3.5.5-Final</version>

  <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.0.Final</version>

  <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
```

Let's say there are two cats ( cat and its mate that have the same kittens ) 
cat/cat's mate has a relationship with it's kittens with kitten's name as join column (OneToMany relationship on join column with a fetch type "eager" )

Let's say I want to get the cats where it's kitten's name is "big", for which, I can write hql in a different ways.

```
I.

hql.append("from Cat as cat ")
hql.append("where cat.kitten.name = 'big' ");

II.

hql.append("from Cat as cat inner join cat.kitten as kitten ")
hql.append("where kitten.name = 'big' ");
```

The aforementioned hql's generate an inner join between cat and it's kitten and is working as expected.

But, if I want to query on a property in kitten with which cat is not joined to kitten ( say location ), I can write hql as follows:

```
III.

hql.append("from Cat as cat ")
hql.append("where cat.kitten.location = 'Chicago' ");

IV.

hql.append("from Cat as cat inner join cat.kitten as kitten ")
hql.append("where kitten.location = 'Chicago' ");
```

*Question 1)  III and IV are working as expected as well, but, the III is generating cartesian/cross join between cat and it's kitten without an explicit join mentioned in the hql, whereas, IV is not. Why is that?*

And

Say, I want to join two "different" objects cat and mate in hql ( which doesn't have any association ) on mate's name, it is generating cross joins.

For instance, if I say,

```
V.

hql.append("select cat ")
hql.append("from Cat as cat, Mate mate ")
hql.append("where cat.location = mate.location and mate.location = 'Chicago' ");
```

It generates cross join.

But, if I say,

```
VI.

hql.append("from Cat as cat ")
hql.append("where cat.location in ( select mate.location from Mate mate where mate.location = 'Chicago' ");
```

*Question 2) It doesn't generate a cross join. But, what if I had to use two columns. I need to use two in clauses to not have a cross join generated by hql. Why does it have to be explicit? or Is there a hibernate configuration to say avoid cross joins if possible?*

Answer (score 0):

In the first forms (I, III, V) the join condition between the tables is defined in the mapping (probably in a `<one-to-many>`, `<many-to.one>`, `<one-to-one>` or `<many-to-many>` clause). It seems in example I you've defined a correct one, and in III and V you didn't do it correctly.

In the examples II, IV and VI you've defined a join (or subselect) explicitly. If there is a join in the HQL statement, Hibernate always uses this join in a single SQL statement (which is not the case if the join is defined in the mapping - Hibernate often prefers two independent selects then (lazy loading works only then)). This is useful if a) there is no join between the tables in the mapping and you need the second table for the where condition or b) for performance reasons when you want to force hibernate to join directly in one statement instead of using two different statements.

If we shall tell you why III and V do not work and produce a cartesian product, then you have to give us the mapping of the tables.